# #Error in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, ssrs-2008, runtime-error, expression

In my report, I have to include All Courses info(in the report) which is in parameter(selected value)

I am using this expression in checkbox:

```
="Course: " & Parameters!Course.Label
```

But this throws an #Error when I run the report. Any idea where am I going wrong.

Thanks,
Ar

Comment: No that din't work unfortunately

Comment: is it a multivalue parameter?

Comment: Aruna, try my answer.

Comment: If my answer solved your question issue you can accept it as the correct answer by clicking on the correct symbol in the left side of my answer. [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
="Course: " & Join(Parameters!Year.Label, ",")
```

If your parameter is multivalue it is necessary to join the labels it returns, if you select multiple values the `join()` function will return comma separated values.

Comment: does this work for multiple NULL values in the parameter list? please let me know

Comment: What do you mean by NULL values in the parameter list? Note the above expression is joining parameter labels not the values. If the labels are null it won't be showed.